# Javascript audio recording to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, audio

how to store a browser audio recording in mongoDB, and how to retrieve it to insert it in the `src` attribute of the html `<audio src=" ">` tag.

Comment: You need to save the audio to a file system or cloud file system, then save the URL to the audio in mongodb

Comment: what kind of file systems for example?

Comment: As @GetOffMyLawn mentioned. You can either save the audio file in your local server's file system or you simply use any cloud file system like Dropbox, OneDrive or Google Drive to upload this file using their API. Then you copy the link to your audio file and save it in mongoDB.

Comment: Look at [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) for storing the audio files in MongoDB. You will still need an API in between the browser and mongo to store and retrieve the files though.

Comment: @getOffMyLawn why overcomplicate things? Patrick is right, this can be stored directly into mongodb

Comment: Just because it can doesn't mean it should. I personally don't like storing files in databases. Let the FS do what it does best... Store and retrieve files.

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked to make this a comment instead of an answer, but StackOverflow says my reputation isn't high enough.

First off, I disagree with @GetOffMyLawn

If you want, you can store files in mongodb. Mongodb can store any file you need, the question is just how is it going to be stored?

I'm not well versed in audio, but I can tell you how I accomplished this exact scenario for video data, and I would assume it would be the same, or similar for audio.

Step 1 is to convert whatever source audio/video you have into a data URI.

The code looks something like this:

```
function getEncodedVideoString($type, $file) {
   return 'data:video/' . $type . ';base64,' . 
   base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
}
```

I copied that from (http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri/)

The exact implementation depends on where the video is being loaded from. Is it coming from the client, is it coming from your server, is it being loaded from an external source? etc.
But the overall principle is the same. Get access to the raw byte data, and then convert it to a base64 string.

Next, once you have the data uri, you can simply store it in mongodb as a text string. Keep in mind, however that when it is encoded to base64, the file size will be about 30% larger because you are encoding byte data as plain text.

If you want, you can also store raw byte data in mongodb, however I have not done this in the past, so I can't exactly speak to how that works.

Lastly, when you need to extract the audio sample, you just query the database for that data uri you just inserted, and send it to your client, and then your clientside code just needs to take the data uri as a string, and append it on the audio element.

It would look something like:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio_element');
audio.src = data_uri_string;
```